# Problem with an easy inequality

Tags: inequality

Help me please with this inequality . I need to prove this inequality, but i don't have any idea how to do this!

$$\frac{(1+\frac{x}{2})^n-1}{(1+x)^2-1}\leq\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Did you try induction on n ?

Comment: I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Check first that the inequality is valid for $n=1$. Assuming it is also valid up to $n = k$ for some integer $k \geq 2,$ prove for $n = k+1$.

Comment: Don't you mean $k\ge 1$ ?

Comment: I proved that inequality is valid for n=1;2;3;4;5;6. But i don't know how to prove that the inequality is valid for n=k.

Comment: You can assume that it is valied for some $n$, and you have to prove that it is valid for $n+1$ then, no matter which value $n$ has.

Comment: I tried to link this inequality with binomial theorem ,but i failed with it.

Comment: What do you know that it is an easy inequaliy ?

Answer (score 2):

use factorization to show
$$
\frac{(1+\frac{x}2)^n-1}{(1+x)^n-1} = \frac12 \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{x}2\right)^k}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k }
$$

Comment: I know nothing about factorization , this task from Intermediate algebra

Comment: $(1-x)(1+x) = 1-x^2; (1-x)(1+x+x^2) = 1-x^3; (1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3)= 1-x^4; (1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)=1-x^5; (1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5) =1-x^6; (1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)=1-x^7$

Comment: Oh, thank you , i understood.